# Regex match if word does not end with

Tags: .net, regex

I am trying to make an algorithm for regex that finds uncalculated calculations such as '15+15', however; it should not match '15+15=30'

So far I have made it work to find calculations such as 15+15, however; it also matches 15+15=30

What I have got so far is

```
\d{1,9}\+\d{1,9}
```

I tried with

```
\d{1,9}\+\d{1,9}[^=]
```

But it didn't really work as I expected.

**I am using the .net 'Regex' class**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a negative lookahead:

```
(\d{1,9}\+\d{1,9})\b(?!=)
```

This asserts that the pattern is not followed by `=`. The `\b` is a word boundary that makes sure that you don't match `15+1` in `15+15=30` (because `5` is not `=`).

The reason why your attempt with the negated character class doesn't work is that it **needs** a non-`=` character after the match.